# With tweepy, how to find tweets from just one country and filter by keywords?

Tags: api, search, tweepy, country-codes

Please, in python3 and with tweepy is it possible to search for tweets only from a certain country and include other types of search?

In the example below I try to search for tweets from Mexico, in Spanish, since 2022-01-01, filtering retweets, and with the terms in the same tweet (activistas+ambientales+criminales)

But returns empty
Does anyone know what could be wrong?

```
import tweepy

consumer_key = ''
consumer_secret = ''
access_token = ''
access_token_secret = ''

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True)

places = api.geo_search(query="Mexico", granularity="country")
place_id = places[0].id
place_id
'25530ba03b7d90c6'

new_search = "place:%s AND activistas+ambientales+criminales -filter:retweets" % (place_id)

tweets = tweepy.Cursor(api.search,
                   q=new_search,
                   lang="es",
                   since='2022-01-01').items(100)
```

Edited 7/9/2022 after Mickael Martinez's reply:

Now I got the tweets! Thanks! I just want to know if the few cases returned are normal:

```
# I upgrade before
!pip install --upgrade tweepy

import pandas as pd
import tweepy

api_key = ''
api_key_secret = ''
bearer_token  = ''

client = tweepy.Client(bearer_token)

# In this query I search for two words + that the tweet is in Spanish + that it is in Mexico + that it is not a retweet
query = "activistas ambientales lang:es place_country:mx -is:retweet"

# I ask to fetch from the beginning of 2022
# And delimit more tweets and user fields
response = client.search_all_tweets(query,
                                    start_time = "2022-01-01T00:00:00Z",
                                    tweet_fields=["id", "author_id", "text", "created_at", "attachments", "context_annotations", "entities", "geo"],
                                    user_fields=["id", "name", "username", "created_at", "description"],
                                    expansions='author_id'
                                    )

tweets = response.data
# Save user data
users = {u["id"]: u for u in response.includes['users']}

# Create a dataframe with the data
my_demo_list = []
for tweet in tweets:
    #print(tweet.id)
    #print(tweet.text)
    #print(tweet.geo)
    
    # captures user data from the tweet that is in the iteration
    author = tweet.author_id
    #print(author)
    for tweetu in response.data:
      if users[tweetu.author_id]:
        user = users[tweetu.author_id]
        if user.id == author:
          name = user.name
          username = user.username
          user_created_at = user.created_at
          user_description = user.description

    my_demo_list.append({'tweet_id': str(tweet.id),
                             'text': str(tweet.text),
                         'name': str(name),
                         'author_id': str(tweet.author_id),
                         'username': str(username),
                         'user_created_at': str(user_created_at),
                         'user_description': str(user_description),
                             'attachments': str(tweet.attachments),
                             'author_id': str(tweet.author_id),
                             'created_at': str(tweet.created_at),
                             'context_annotations': str(tweet.context_annotations),
                             'entities': str(tweet.entities),
                             'geo': str(tweet.geo)
                            })

all_tweets_found = pd.DataFrame(my_demo_list)
all_tweets_found.shape
(10, 12)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The place operator seems to be a premium operator in the Twitter V1.1 API (see the documentation [here](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/premium/search-api/guides/operators)), so I'm not sure that you can use it in the standard search method.

Since you probably have an elevated access, you should update to the latest version of Tweepy and you may have access to the `search_30_days` method. Maybe that you can use the place operator in it. If that does not work, I guess that you will have to pay for a premium access.

**Edit after your comment:**

Since you have an academic access, I would sugest you to:

- Update Tweepy to its current 4.10.0 version (`pip install --upgrade tweepy`) because, based on your code, you seem to be using an outdated 3.X.X version.
- That will allow you to use the V2 of the Twitter API and particularly the `search_all_tweets` method in Tweepy (see [here](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/client.html#search-tweets)) where you can use `place` and `place_country` operators.
- There will a few changes to make to your code to adapt it to the 4.X version of Tweepy and the V2 of the Twitter API. The following code could be a first draft for example:

```py
query = ""
bearer_token = ""

client = tweepy.Client(bearer_token)

response = client.search_all_tweets(query)

print(response.data)
print(response.meta)
print(response.includes)
print(response.errors)

tweets = response.data

for tweet in tweets:
    print(tweet.id)
    print(tweet.text)
```

And you could read the documentation [here](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/search/integrate/build-a-query) to build the query.

But... do you *really* need to use Tweepy? Are you building an app for future users or are you just gathering data for your research? If the second answer is the good one, I would strongly suggest you to use [Twarc](https://twarc-project.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), a command-line tool which is more suited for this purpose.

Comment: Hello. Thank you very much @Mickael Martinez I don't have premium access. I have a Standalone App and another project with Academic Research (V1.1 ACCESS and V2 ACCESS) where I can create apps. That's enough? And how can I update the version of Tweepy? And how to use search_30_days?

Comment: @ReinaldoChaves I updated my answer to answer thoses questions and to take into consideration that you have an academic access. Hope it helps!

Comment: Hello. Thank you so much @Mickael Martinez. I commented above in my question. Basically it worked great, thanks. But the number of tweets returned is small. I just want to confirm: is this because it is likely that there are few georeferenced tweets from Mexico with the delimitations I made?

Comment: @ReinaldoChaves You should set the `max_results` argument in search_all_tweets (default is 10 and it can be set up to 500). In you need more results than that, you will have to use pagination (which works with the `Paginator` class (see [here](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/v2_pagination.html)) and not the `Cursor` used for the V1).